# $scope http data indefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an error when i declare a variable to get an element from my data of json file in external of my function, somebody can explain me why plz ?

produit.json :

```
[{
"id" : 1,
"reference": "AA"
},
{
"id" : 2,
"reference": "BB"
}]
```

angulars.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http,$log) {

    $http.get('produits.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.produits = data;
        $scope.ref1= $scope.produits[0].reference; //OK

    });

    $scope.ref1= $scope.produits[0].reference; //ERROR: undefined produits
});
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       Reférence 1 :  {{ ref1 }}     // ERROR
   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It gives your error because you're calling $scope out of  your controller where it is defined. You should just delete that call or, if you want to access ref1 from a different controller/script/directive, defining a service which gets it for your (factory should be fine).

Comment: Let me know if you solve with it or need other help.

Answer (score 1):

Until the service returns results,`$scope.produits` is not defined yet. And even if it was, then it would not have a `[0]` element.

So i think the best way would be to not add the last line of your code and just wait for the service to return results:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http,$log) {

        $http.get('produits.json').success(function (data) {

            $scope.produits = data;
            $scope.ref1= $scope.produits[0].reference; //OK

    });


});
```

Comment: thank you, i need to call on my html page that :   {{ produit[ {{refSelected}}].reference}}   refSelected is a variable in my model, it change by the view  !     how can i do this plz ?

Comment: It will show when you get the response from your get request.

Comment: yes,  i mean {{ produit[ {{ refSelected}} ].reference  doesn't work !

Comment: It id produits and not produit. Also i do not see a refSelected somewhere.

Comment: <td> <img  ng-click="selectProduct(1)"/></td>                                      ref  : {{ produit[ {{ refSelected }}].reference  // ERROR                                                                                                   angular.js :                                                                                        $scope.refSelected= 0;                                                  $scope.selectProduct = function (item) {$scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.refSelected= item;
  });
    };

Comment: would you try `{{ produits[refSelected].reference}}` . Make note i wrote produits. If yopu have it produit (which i think you do not), then remove the s.

Answer (score 0):

The code above which you have written is doing an asynchronous call, that is, when-ever you make an http call it takes some time to get the response, but the javascript code continues to run , so until the response is returned the success callback has not been called, as a result your $scope.produits is not defined until that point of time

Comment: thank you for your response, but any solution to do that other way plz ?